# Show tooltips of piechart when hover outside of the chart on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/39UXK/4/

in this example I want to see the tooltips of the piechart when I hover on the respected buttons.

Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the point in question, select it, and refresh the tooltip:

```
// find the point
var point = chart.series[0].points[i];

// select the point
point.select();

// refresh the tooltip
chart.tooltip.refresh(point);
```