# how can i show a tool tip on pie chart's each section using javascript canvas programming

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

how can i  show a tool tip  on pie chart's each section using javascript  without using any js library like kinetic, Raphael  etc, and how to separate each section of pie's on mouse click, on mouse over showing tooltip.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function draw()
{

 var can=document.getElementById("can");
 var ctx=can.getContext("2d");

 var w=can.width/2;
 var h=can.height/2; 
  var total=startangle=endangle=radius=slices=0;
  var data=[25,25,25,25];

  var color=['red','green','blue','purple'];
  var subdata=[2,5];
  //collecting total value of pie
  for(var k =0;k<data.length;k++)
   {
total+=data[k];  
   }
  //generate pie
   for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
 slices=(data[i]/total);
 radius=2*Math.PI*slices;
 endangle=startangle+radius;
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(w, h, 75, startangle, endangle);
 ctx.lineTo(w,h);
 ctx.closePath();
 startangle+=radius;
 ctx.fillStyle=color[i];
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.lineWidth=2;

 ctx.stroke();
 }
 }

    </script>
```

Comment: This Link will help you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671227/show-tooltips-of-piechart-when-hover-outside-of-the-chart-on-a-button

Answer (score 3):

Luckily, Matt Doyle and Simon Meek over at Elated.com have a tutorial that shows exactly what you're looking for.  Check it out: http://www.elated.com/articles/snazzy-animated-pie-chart-html5-jquery/